# How to create link that opens an email to your personal email address

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a link that will lead people to my personal email address. Please, help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`mailto`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) protocol:

```html
<a href="mailto:example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
```

Clicking the link will attempt to open the default email client of the user, and prepopulate the `to` field in the email with the address specified.